# Can I load a dropdown list with a SharePoint list to set a Custom Web Part Property?

Tags: web-part, web-part-property

I found this post which claims to show you how to do it:

http://blog.concurrency.com/sharepoint/create-a-custom-web-part-for-sharepoint-2010/comment-page-1/#comment-1851

But after carefully following the instructions and downloading the code, I have not been able to get it to work as expected.

I posted a similar question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11118/possible-to-have-users-configure-a-few-values-when-adding-a-webpart-to-a-page), but the answers only told me how I could load a drop down list with static values.  I would like to load it from a SharePoint list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abe you said:

> I downloaded the source but it only
>   appears to work with the static drop
>   down list of items. I followed your
>   instructions but was never able to get
>   the drop down working with an internal
>   list. Is this possible to do by
>   following the instructions you have
>   provided? If so, would it be possible
>   to get you to post up the working code
>   for that?

In the source you need to add an override of `CreateEditorParts`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.iwebeditable.createeditorparts.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.createeditorparts.aspx

```
public override EditorPartCollection CreateEditorParts() {
    ArrayList editorArray = new ArrayList();
    MyEditorPart edPart = new MyEditorPart();
    edPart.ID = this.ID + "_editorPart1";
    editorArray.Add(edPart);
    EditorPartCollection editorParts = new EditorPartCollection(editorArray);
    return editorParts;
}
```

So the webpart will use the custom editor parts.

Comment: You rock, I will give this a shot.

Answer (score 2):

I have a custom ToolPart that reads from a database, but you could change it to read from a SPList instead

```
public class CustomToolPart : ToolPart {

    protected override void CreateChildControls() {
        ddlCustom = new DropDownList();
        ddlCustom.ID = "ddlCustom";
        ddlCustom.ToolTip = "Custom";
        try {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(this.webPart.ConnectionString)) {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select id,name from [sometableftdb_forums]", conn);
                SqlDataAdapter rs = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                rs.Fill(ds, "Data");
                ddlCustom.DataSource = ds;
                ddlCustom.DataTextField = "name";
                ddlCustom.DataValueField = "id";
                ddlCustom.DataBind();
                ddlCustom.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("(choose)", "0"));
            }

            //instead add code here for SPSite/SPWeb/SPList

        } catch (SqlException ex) {
            ddlCustom.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("(sql error)", "0"));
        }
        ListItem item = ddlCustom.Items.FindByValue((webPart != null ? webPart.CustomValueId : 0).ToString());
        if (item != null) {
            ddlCustom.SelectedIndex = -1;
            item.Selected = true;
        }
        Controls.Add(ddlCustom);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this approach is for web parts created as SharePoint WSS 2.0 web parts (Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart) rather than ASP.Net web parts as the questioner is referring to. (Note that there are circumstances when one may need the former).